# Exporting data from database to csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I am able to export database to csv but my code somehow imports twice the data to my csv file. I.e  same column twice side by side.this is my code. I think my problem is with the implode statment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$db = new sqlite3('I:\preethi\webbs.db');

$headers = array

('Id','CompanyId','DateTime','Serial','DeviceId','AgentAId','GpsAddress','Targa','CommonRoadDescription'

,'RoadCivicNumber','VehicleBrandDescription','VehicleModelDescription' ,'VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription','CommonColorVehicleDescription','VerbaliRuleOneCode','VerbaliRuleOneDes

cription','VerbaliRuleOnePoints'  

    ,'VerbaliClosedNoteDescription','Points','VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription 

','MissedNotificationNote','StatementNote');

    $results = $db->query('select'.implode (',',$headers).'from VerbaliData');

    //$results = $db->query( 'select 
Id   ,CompanyId  ,DateTime  ,Serial  ,DeviceId  ,AgentAId  

,GpsAddress  ,Targa  ,CommonRoadDescription  ,RoadCivicNumber  ,VehicleBrandDescription  

,VehicleModelDescription  ,VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription  ,CommonColorVehicleDescription  

,VerbaliRuleOneCode  ,VerbaliRuleOneDescription  ,VerbaliRuleOnePoints  ,VerbaliClosedNoteDescription  

,Points  ,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  ,MissedNotificationNote  ,StatementNote  from 

VerbaliData');


    $fp = fopen('explores.csv', 'w');

    fputcsv($fp,$headers);

    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
             fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    ?>
```

Comment: "imports twice the data to my csv file" or "imports twice the data to my db"?

Comment: exporting data from sqlite 3 to csv.. but instead it exports twice like ('Id','ID','CompanyId', 'comapnayID','DateTime','datetime','serial','Serial'

Comment: Can you just copy paste output CSV data in pastebin.com?

Comment: done. titles sql to csv. headers appearing once but data twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with :

```
while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM)) {
```

Or

```
while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
```

More Details: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php

Comment: @preethi Ok I'll check. It would be better if you could provide CSV pastebin URL.

Comment: With `SQLITE3_NUM` or `SQLITE_ASSOC` It should have worked. If that still didn't work, Just use `array_unique`($row) before fputcsv($fp, $row);

Comment: 2 errors :Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "selectId": syntax error in C:\xampp\htdocs\download.php on line 11

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\download.php on line 18

Comment: @preethi Can you provide table dump & full code. I'll have a look on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45628/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-preethi)

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight prob in your code fetchArray() returns two array sets one associative and one is numbered, use fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM) or fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC).